# Autlolayout not updating frames by the time call to systemLayoutSizeFitting(:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:) is made

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I have UITableViewCell subclass. The xib looks like below:
[image]

On launching the app I get the cell rendered as below as I change the content view with a custom lock view. The rotation from portrait to landscape is also done:
[image]

[image]

After rotating from landscape to portrait the layout is weird as below:
[image]

In the UITableViewCell subclass I have overridden the method `systemLayoutSizeFitting(:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:)`.

The implementation is as below:

```
override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        
        
        print("customContentView.bounds:", customContentView.bounds)
        
        verticalStackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({
            $0.sizeToFit()
            $0.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

        verticalStackView.setNeedsLayout()
        verticalStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        
       
        let customContentViewHorizontalPadding = customContentViewLeadingConstraint.constant + customContentViewTrailingConstraint.constant
        let customContentViewVerticalPadding = customContentViewTopConstraint.constant + customContentViewBottomConstraint.constant
        
        var _adjustedTargetSize = targetSize
        _adjustedTargetSize.width -= customContentViewHorizontalPadding
        _adjustedTargetSize.height -= customContentViewVerticalPadding
        var size = customContentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(_adjustedTargetSize)

        
        let collectionViewContentSize = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
        size.height += collectionViewContentSize.height
        
        
        size.height += customContentViewVerticalPadding
        size.width += customContentViewHorizontalPadding
        
        return size
    }
```

Upon testing the rotation from landscape to portrait I have found that the target size sent in to the method has a larger width then required for portrait, which results in a smaller height calculation and messing up the interface.

Why is the system passing in a larger width then required in this rotation?. How do I correct this?

Note: If I remove the override of the method the collection view inside the stack view seems to be totally ignored in the calculation as evident with the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`systemLayoutSizeFitting` is not something you override, it’s something you call. And a stack view is already self sizing from its contents so your code would be pointless in any case. As this is a table cell, just configure constraints and let the runtime size the height.

Comment: If i dont override the method, the collectionview content size inside the stackview is never considered for the layout, that is the reason I have added an override. This is the result I get if I remove the override https://rohanbhale-gmail.tinytake.com/tt/NDQ3MjcwMl8xNDE2MDQ4OA

Comment: So there's a collection view inside a stack view? I'm surprised that that ever worked. In that case, the collection view needs something that determines its height, such as an intrinsic content size override. The details depend on what the stack view is configured for. Personally I regard the stack view as overkill in this situation; I don't see what purpose it serves.

Comment: I find the workaround of using a height constraint and observing the content size of the collection view a bit messy in terms of code as well as the ui result. Is there a better solution than that?